# Fields: Prove $1+1=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose F has four elements Prove that $1+1=0$

I know that for $F=\{0,1\}$, $1+1 =0$ because if $1+1 =1$, then $1=0$, which is not true, by the definition of field

Comment: Looks like your coursemate from a suburb near to yours asked this first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any field $F$ is an abelian group under its addition operation.  There are two nonisomorphic groups of order $4$, namely $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

If the former is the case, then we are done as every nonidentity element has order $2$.  Can the latter be true?  If it is, then either $a$ or $b$ must have order $2$.  In other words, either $a+a = 0$ or $b+b = 0$.  From this, we can use the distributive property to write either $a(1+1) = 0$ or $b(1+1) = 0$.

To finish up, you'll want to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are elements of any field, then $xy = 0 \iff x = 0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: thanks but i dont get how proving xy=0 shows that 1+1=0, like ik how to prove it but dont get it

Comment: If we have either $a(1+1) = 0$ or $b(1+1) = 0$, and we know that $a, b \neq 0$, then $1+1 = 0$ will be forced.

Comment: so with the prove i get y=0, so that means 1+1=0?

Comment: Yeah. The $y$ would be the $1+1$ above.

Comment: Yep, that looks good.

Comment: sorry to disturb u again but i still dont get it, like how do i explain y=0, proves 1+1=0

Comment: We know either $a(1+1) = 0$ or $b(1+1) =  0$.  Since the $x$ and $y$ are generic, just take $a = x$ (or $b=x$ if the other was the case) and $1+1 = y$.

Answer (score 1):

the characteristic of a finite ring divides the order of the ring.

The characteristic of a finite domain is a prime.